# the method getInstance() isn't defined for 'screenutil' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on flutter project .I'm trying to fix errors on my project after migration to null safety . I have error on this line :

```
SizedBox(
           height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(35),
          ),
```

error : the method 'getinstance' isn't defined for the type 'screenutil'

with flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0

How I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) the correct implementation is:

```dart
ScreenUtil().setHeight(35)
```